# store a variable if a value exits in an object when parsing the object in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object like the following:

```
{
"_attrib": {
    "PieChart": "T",
    "ProductSettings": "true"
},
"WATER": {
    "_attrib": {
        "Step": "5",
        "ProgressAdjust": "41",
    }
},
"TEMP": {
    "_attrib": {
        "Argument": "F7",
        "Default": "00"
    },
    "ITEM": [
        {
            "_attrib": {
                "Name": "Low",
            }
        },
        {
            "_attrib": {
                "Name": "Normal",
            }
        },
        {
            "_attrib": {
                "Name": "High",
            }
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

what I need to parse is to find where ProgressAdjust is set and then add the name in this case WATER into an array,

I have the following code however the array has all the names (i.e: _attrib, water, temp).

```
export const productCustomizationOptions = (product: any) => {
  const options = [];
  Object.entries(product.product).forEach((item1, index1) => {
    Object.values(item1[1]).forEach((item2) => {
      if (item2.ProgressAdjust !== 'undefined') {
        options.push(item1[0]);
      }
    });
 });
 console.log('customization options: ', options);
};
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your object structured the way you showed in the question? `_attrib` is somewhere the root prop and somewhere its nested two levels deep.

Comment: yes the object is exactly like that. they indicate attributes for different items

Comment: So, if any of the `_attrib` prop inside `ITEM` array has `ProgressAdjust` you want to add `ITEM` to the result array?

Comment: the ProgressAdjust only shows up in the higher level _attrib for example in WATER and TEMP,  and if it shows in one of those I need to add WATER or TEMP into the array

Comment: Please take a look at my answer and let me know if it solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues @akano1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using `Object.entries` convert the object into an array of key/value pairs
- Filter this array using `Array#filter` and [Optional Chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

> The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

- Finally using `Array#map` extract out only the keys

```js
const 
  obj = {_attrib:{PieChart:"T",ProductSettings:"true"},WATER:{_attrib:{Step:"5",ProgressAdjust:"41"}},TEMP:{_attrib:{Argument:"F7",Default:"00"},ITEM:[{_attrib:{Name:"Low"}},{_attrib:{Name:"Normal"}},{_attrib:{Name:"High"}}]}},
  
  res = Object.entries(obj).filter(([, o]) => o?._attrib?.ProgressAdjust).map(([k]) => k)

console.log(res)
```